# How to remove Empty values from dataframe without having Nonetype or KeyType Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to drop empty values from a column in data frame after which I need to perform a for loop with keeping the range as the length of the same column.

I have tried various things to drop the empty values but each of them are either giving
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error
or
Key Error :2744
with the row where the first empty value was there.

The errors arise when I try this statement.

```
for i in range(len(df_new['Column'])):
```

Below are the drop statements i have tried.

```
df_new=original_df.dropna(subset=['Column'],inplace=True)
```

Error:
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error

```
df_new=df_original[df_original['Column'].notnull()]
```

Error:
Key Error :2744

How can i over come this
Please let me know.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with this statement: `df_new=original_df.dropna(subset=['Column'],inplace=True)`:

`inplace=True` modifies the `original_df` dataframe and returns `None`, therefore your statement is equivalent to `df_new = None`, which not subscriptable, hence the error.

So you either want:

```
df_new=original_df.dropna(subset=['Column'],inplace=False) #inplace defaults to False, but including for clarity
#or
original_df.dropna(subset=['Column'],inplace=True) #NaNs in the original dataframe are replaced
```